# Change group owner in IMO messanger and asign group administrator

Tags: android

I'm using [IMO messanger](https://imo.im/). (on Android)

I have created a group with 5 members.

1- How can I change the group owner?

2- May the group have administrator members, who able take changes in group?

Helps are appreciated.